# Given nodes of a graph on a circle, find minimum number of nodes to be removed to have a graph in which each node has edge to its next node

Tags: algorithm

Given n people sitting at the table, some of people are familiar with each other, familiarity is a bidirectional relation, find minimum number of people to be eliminated from the table in order to have a table that each person at the table is familiar with its neighbors. Give a solution of O(n^2)

My current effort:
As the order suggests, I tried solving the problem by T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n),
But if I consider I have found the ideal circle with m nodes envolving in it and now I want to add a new node, I check new node if it can be new member for the circle and make new circle of m+1 nodes, if it is possible then the problem is solved, but if it is not, I do need to store all circles of length m-1, m-2,... and add this new node to them which takes more than O(n) time.

Comment: Check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs
I don't think O(n^2) is possible.

Comment: @srinath people at the table do not need to know everybody at the table only neighbors (I assume an arbitrarily taken person has to know (at least) the one on its left and on its right but not mandatorily everyone else)

Comment: @user753642 ok, so basically we need to find the longest cycle in an undirected graph. This problem can be reduced to finding Hamiltonian Cycle problem which in-turn is NP-complete.

Comment: Is the table round? which means the first and the last person are neighbour?

Comment: @Pham Trung yes it is

Comment: It is my homework, and I know I should solve it by one of  dinamic/ greedy/ devide and conquer algorithms @Srinath

Comment: @Mahsirat is it allowed to rearrange peoples?

Comment: No it is not, @Srinath

Comment: @Mahsirat okay, then it can be solved using dynamic programming, but the solution I have is of O(n^3) time.

Answer (score 2):

Let assume that we have a graph with `n` nodes, `0 to n - 1`.

If we view the problem as finding the shortest cycle from node A back to A, the distance between node `a` and `b` is the absolute different `(b - a - 1)` (which is all the nodes between those two) and we could only go from `a` to `b` if `b > a` or `a` is the start node. This problem is reduced to classic finding the shortest path in the graph.

Using Dijkstra algo, we could obtain a O(N^2 log N) algorithm.

Java code:

```java
class State{
    int node, distance;
}
int result = n - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //Find the shortest path to move from i -> i
    PriorityQueue<State> q = new PriorityQueue<>((a , b) -> Integer.compare(a.distance, b.distance));
    for(int j : map[i]) {
        if( j > i){
            q.add(new State(j , j - i + 1);
        }
    }  

    int[]dist = new int[n];
    Arrays.fill(dist, n - 1);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
          State s = q.poll();
          if(s.distance != dist[s.node]){
               continue;
          }
          for(int j : map[s.node]){
               if((j > s.node || j == i) && dist[j] > s.distance + (j - s.node + 1)){
                    dist[j] = s.distance + (j - s.node + 1);
                    q.add(new State(j, dist[j]);
               }
          }
    }
    result = Integer.min(result, dist[i]);
}
```